# Ubuntu 14.04 How do I fix the imaplib.readonly error?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, imap

I'm trying to use an imap script to view emails from a server. My script is able to log in fine, I get the 'OK Logged in' message, it's able to list the mailvoxes and dump untagged responses. After this, the message is as follows:

```
  File "imap_email.py", line 134, in <module>
    mailbox = get_mailbox(connection)
  File "imap_email.py", line 98, in get_mailbox
    rv, data = connection.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 671, in select
    raise self.readonly('%s is not writable' % mailbox)
imaplib.readonly: INBOX is not writable
```

I was earlier getting an error that stated that imaplib couldn't parse the X-Original-To header. I removed that by adding "enable_original_recipient = no" to my postfix's **main.cf**.

Can somebody explain to me what this error is and possible causes for it? IMAP, SMTP, Postfix and Dovecot are all new to me, I'm a newbie.

My current setup involves a client and server VM, both running Ubuntu 14.04 and identical in every way. I have 1 user setup on each named client1 and server1 respectively, they are the ones receiving/sending emails. I should also note that I'm able to send (smtp) emails fine and examine my mailbox through curl commands.

Comment: Support may be difficult since 14.04 no longer receives community support.

Comment: Right, I forgot, thank you!